# How do I determine which form of Toxtricity I will get?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

In Sword & Shield, there is a new Pokémon called Toxel, which can evolve into Toxtricity. What is interesting about Toxtricity is that it can be one of two forms

- Amped Form
- Low Key Form

When Toxel evolves into Toxtricity, how did I determine which form it will take on? And what are the differences between the two forms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how did I determine which form it will take on?

The form [Toxtricity](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Toxtricity_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) takes on is based on it's nature.

- **Amped Form**:  Hardy, Brave, Adamant, Naughty, Docile, Impish, Lax, Hasty, Jolly, Naive, Rash, Sassy, or Quirky.
- **Lowkey Form**: Lonely, Bold, Relaxed, Timid, Serious, Modest, Mild, Quiet, Bashful, Calm, Gentle, or Careful.

> what are the differences between the two forms?

There are a few of differences between the two forms.

- Abilities: Low Key and Amped both get the abilities Punk Rock and Technician (hidden). The difference here is that Low Key gets the ability Minus whereas Amped gets the ability Plus.
- Moves: A majority of the move pool is the same, but there are some differences. Low Key Form can get the moves Venom Drench   and Magnetic Flux, but Amped Form cannot.  Amped Formed Venoshock and Shift Gear, but Low Key Form cannot

Comment: Has it been confirmed that the nature mints affect toxel's evolution? I've heard the opposite, where nature mints let you give it whatever stat boost/drop you want because it's the written nature that determines the form

Comment: @Pyritie I heard the opposite of that, but let me do more research. In the mean time, I'll take it out until it's been more researched

Comment: Mints does not count for the amped form (tested today)

Comment: @LamaDelRay Thanks for verifying that! My bad on originally adding that incorrect information - my source was apparently incorrect on that matter

Comment: @Wondercricket No trouble, mine said that too. I've wasted a mint but that's not that bad.